# How to search integer value in sequelize using where clause

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to search for an integer value using where clause in sequelize.
There are three fields among them two are text type for which search is working fine, but for the integer it is not. I have used the following code for doing this:

```
'description': {
    $like: '%' + search.general + '%'
}
```

search.general is the value from the html file where I have a textbox. I have used same format for searching 'id', but i have got the following error:

> **ERROR**:  operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown at character 321
>
> **HINT**:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
> might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: try `$like: '%' + search.id + '::text%'` which basically is just casting int to text

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your $like to this

```
'%\'||cast(' + search.general + ') as text||\'%'
```

Please post your final sql string if it doesn't work

Comment: well, I wanted to cast the id to text not the search.general as integer/text, because it is text type already.

Comment: do you want find integer 12 in 123?